# @font-face: Chrome detects font perfectly, but margin appears

Tags: html, css, font-face, margin, padding

```
<style>
    @font-face
    {
        font-family : 'Avenir';
        src         : url("/fonts/Avenir999.otf");
    }

    p.price a span
    {
    /*font-family   : 'Avenir';*/
      font-size     : 45px;
      color: #889900;
    }

</style>
<p class="price" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <a href="#"><span>this text is above the middle of red rectangle if uncomment //font-family</span></a>
</p>
```

Again, the font is detected properly. Everything works fine. If I use

```
p.price a span
{
  font-size     : 45px;
  color: #889900;
}
```

then it is perfect.
But, once I add a string font-face so that

```
p.price a span
{
  font-family   : 'Avenir';
  font-size     : 45px;
  color: #889900;
}
```

the font style changes (great!), but it jumps up almost out of the red 1px solid rectangle. Why? How to fix? Why it happens? that's just the font. No padding, no margin is used.

Firefox is OK, but Chrome is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It must be something wrong with your font file. I would use [Font Squirrel's](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) font generator to build your font files to use with @font-face. It will generate the cross-browser CSS for you to use that should work better across different browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Tried but it didn't help - it doesn't detect that font from new files although I've put them into the same folder and wrote the same paths @ css file.

Comment: You might need to remove the `/` from the start of the font file path for example: `src: url('fonts/avenirltstd-light-webfont.eot');`